# How can i write the JSON data shown in my Linux terminal to a JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, linux, terminal

Guys so what this script does is: reads a file which is not proper JSON format and writes it to a proper JSON format but on my terminal. i want it to directly write the read data to a JSON file. i need it to look exactly how it looks like in my Terminal window.
Please show me an example of some sort, i really appreciate the help.----->
[My terminal window with values in correct JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olnlp.png)

```
import json
from pprint import pprint




data = []
with open(r"latency.json") as fp:
    while True:
        l= fp.readline()
        if not l:
            break
            
        j = json.loads( l )
        data.append( j )
pprint( data )
```

Comment: The output in your terminal is not valid JSON.

Comment: That looks like a list of dictionaries. Actual JSON keys are quoted with `"`

Comment: If your output is fine, you can just redirect it with `your_command > output.txt` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import yaml 

FILE_PATH = ''

with open(f'{FILE_PATH}.json', 'r') as fileRead:
     TEMP = fileRead.readlines()

for line in TEMP:
    DATA = yaml.load(line.strip(), yaml.SafeLoader)
    print(json.dumps(DATA))
```